# RecyclerView radio button won't register only the latest checked item (remember previous too)

Tags: java, android

I have RecyclerView which has multiple items, those items contain radio buttons, course name (TextView) and hole number (TextView).
What supposes to happen is that when I click the radio button, it should select only that 1, and if there are the previous check it should uncheck it (single selection). Well at the moment It checks only 1 at a time which is ok (so frontend works as it should), but what happens "under the hood"... example:

There are currently 3 items in RecyclerView. I click the third item to be checked, then I click first, and again third. now I click "start game" button, what should happen is that it should take that lastly checked item (in this case the third left lastly selected) and intent its course name and hole number to the next Activity, but instead what happens now is that it intent the first items course name and hole number... Also if I do the same as previous, but instead of clicking first item, I click second, then even tho lastly I clicked that third item, instead intent its course name and hole number, it intents that second items... So it always intents that item which is clicked (at some point) and from those clicked items it checks the first 1 (from top to bottom of a list) and take its intents.

Here is my Adapter where I'm checking which 1 is selected:

```
public class NewGameCourseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewGameCourseAdapter.NewGameCourseViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<NewGameCourseItem> mCourseList;
    private NewGamePlayerAdapter.OnItemsCheckStateListener checkStateListener;


private NewGameCourseAdapter.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(NewGameCourseAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
    itemClickListener = listener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemsCheckStateListener(NewGamePlayerAdapter.OnItemsCheckStateListener checkStateListener) {
    this.checkStateListener = checkStateListener;
}

public static class NewGameCourseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public RadioButton mRadioButton;

        public NewGameCourseViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final NewGameCourseAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mRadioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        }
    }
```

onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewGameCourseViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final NewGameCourseItem currentItem = mCourseList.get(position);

        /** This can prevent some unwanted actions in some cases **/
        holder.mRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        holder.mRadioButton.setChecked(selectedPosition == position);

        holder.mRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                if (itemClickListener != null) {
                    itemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the Activity where I do the intent:

```
        mStartGame = findViewById(R.id.button_start_game);

        mStartGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mCourseList.size(); i++) {
                    /** If radio button is selected, then intent to ActivityGame **/
                    if (mCourseList.get(i).getRadioButton() == true) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityNewGame2.this, ActivityGame.class);

                        /** Also intent selected items course name and hole number **/
                        intent.putExtra("COURSENAME", mCourseList.get(i).getCourseName());
                        intent.putExtra("HOLESNM", mCourseList.get(i).getHolesNm());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Summary: in frontend it looks correct, it selects only that radio button which is lastly clicked and uncheck the previous (as it should), but inside, it won't "forget" the previous selections as it should do...

Comment: Your description seems confusing to me. Is it the case where there is a RecyclerView, now each recyclerview item has a radio button. Once one radio is selected then previously selected radio item will be removed from selection in term of layout and item position track in code too and currently selected radio will be updated. Now the selected item data will be sent to an another Activity. Please confirm if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something weird, if possible make that simple.

**Step 1: Create a method to get the selected item in your adapter class**

```
public NewGameCourseItem getSelectedItem() {
   return mCourseList.get(selectedPosition);
}
```

**Step 2: Then modify your on click method like below**

```
mStartGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         NewGameCourseItem  item = adapter.getSelecteditem();
         Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityNewGame2.this, ActivityGame.class);
         /** Also intent selected items: course name and hole number **/
         intent.putExtra("COURSENAME", item.getCourseName());
         intent.putExtra("HOLESNM", item.getHolesNm());
         startActivity(intent);
         overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
      }
 });
```

**Step 3: Now modify your onCheckedChanged as below**

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
     notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
     selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
     notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
 }
```

Comment: remove your first `notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);` statement

Comment: No, that is for invalidate the previous selection, that is needed.

Comment: still  the same issue

Comment: @Krishna Sharma I couldn't do this itemClickListener.onItemClick(<your-list>.get(position)); instead what I did was itemClickListener.onItemClick(position); but now, nothing happens when I click "start game" button

Comment: Does your itemClickListener method get called, make sure that you have initialized in adapter constructor. <your-list> it was list that you have used in adapter getitemCount.

Comment: I change my question code in order you to see that, cause I'm pretty confused right now, I'm not sure where should I put which code

Comment: @Krishna Sharma You forgot that if should do intent only after user click "start game" button, Now it intent right away user click radio button

Comment: @antsakontsa My bad, I misunderstood your requirement. Now have corrected that. Now even you don't need OnItemClickListener , you can remove this

Comment: @antsakontsa Glad to hear. Thank you.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma is it possible to use notifyDataSetChanged instead of this notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition); cause now when I click the radio button, that flashes whole item and also that item where it uncheck the item, its guick white flash on whole item. Its not necessary to get rid off but I would like it better if its not flashing

Comment: Yes you can use `notifyDataSetChanged`, only difference is `notifyDataSetChanged` will refresh entire list where as `notifyItemChanged` will just refresh the item for the specified position. Ideally flashing shouldn't had to be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class variable in adapter

```
private int selectedPosition = -1; //change -1 to any default position, need to be selected.
```

Modify the below function in adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewGameCourseViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final NewGameCourseItem currentItem = mCourseList.get(position);

    holder.mRadioButton.setChecked(selectedPosition == position);

    holder.mRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                int tempSelected = selectedPosition;
                selectedPosition = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Create a new method in adapter as below-

```
public int getSelectedItemIndex() {
    return selectedPosition;
}
```

I assume `adapter` is the variable of `NewGameCourseAdapter` in the Activity class. Modify the button click in the Activity:

```
mStartGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int selectedRecyclerItemPosition = adapter.getSelectedItemIndex();

        //Calling intent and pass selected item info
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityNewGame2.this, ActivityGame.class);
        /** Also intent selected items course name and hole number **/
        intent.putExtra("COURSENAME", mCourseList.get(selectedRecyclerItemPosition).getCourseName());
        intent.putExtra("HOLESNM", mCourseList.get(selectedRecyclerItemPosition).getHolesNm());
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
});
```